# How do display functions like sprintf convert numbers to strings?

Tags: c++, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to extract the integer and decimal parts of a floating point value, and I seem to be running into some strange rounding problems, due probably to the imprecise way floats are stored.

I have some code like this to extract the fractional part:

```
double number = 2.01;
int frac = int(floor(number * 100)) % 100;
```

However the result here instead of 1 comes out as 0.  This seems to be because the original double actually gets stored as:

```
2.0099999...
```

However running sprintf seems to get such a conversion correct:

```
char num_string[99];
sprintf(num_string,"%f",number);
```

How is sprintf getting the correct answer while the above method does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>> However the result here instead of 1 comes out as one.</s>

What do you mean?

> 2.099999...

Or, more like `2.00999...`

As you've noted:

```
int frac = int(floor(number * 100)) % 100;
```

will be:

```
int frac = int(floor(2.00999... * 100)) % 100;
         = int(floor(200.999...)) % 100;
         = int(floor(200.999...)) % 100;
         = int(200) % 100;
         = 200 % 100;
         = 0;
```

You may be interested in [this](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/lib/msun/src/s_floor.c?rev=1.8&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).

Also, see `modf` from `math.h`:

```
double modf(double x, double *intptr) /* Breaks x into fractional and integer parts. */
```

modf() is a better alternative than doing the juggling yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors, I really should avoid writing such questions late at night.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with dirkgently on using modf from math.h. But if you must do the juggling yourself, try this code. This should work around the problem you see.

```
int round(double a) {
    if (a > 0)
        return int(a + 0.5);
    else
        return int(a - 0.5);
}

int main()
{
    double number = 2.01;
    int frac = round((number - ((int)number)) * 100);
    printf("%d", frac);
}
```

Comment: The standard does not define _tmain().